# How to read URL parameters in laravel

Tags: laravel, routes, middleware, laravel-middleware, referrals

I am begginer, and trying to create a referral system. following is sample url

```
http://dev.lea.com/register?ref=mh2HPLpVSn
```

I try to get referral string. how can i get separately? is there need of middleware for getting cookies? if yes then what will be code of middleware? and how can i get referral reference in RegisterController?

Here is my Register Controller.

```
<?php

namespace Lea\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use DB;
use Lea\User;
use Lea\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Cookie;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'fname' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'lname' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'referral' => 'string|max:255',
            'username' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
            // 'tracking_id' => 'required',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Lea\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data, Request $request)
    {

        //  printing here referral Link
        echo $request()->ref;


        // $referred_by = Cookie::get();
        // print_r($referred_by); 
        die;

        return User::create([
            'fname' => $data['fname'],
            'lname' => $data['lname'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'affiliate_id' => str_random(10),
            // 'referred_by' => $referred_by,
            'identity' => $data['identity'],
            'dob' => $data['dob'],
            'board_id' => $data['board_id'],
            'class_id' => $data['class_id'],
            'subject_id' => $data['subject_id'],
            'institute' => $data['institute'],
            'address' => $data['address'],
            'city' => $data['city'],
            'std_mobile' => $data['std_mobile'],
            'father_name' => $data['father_name'],
            'father_mobile' => $data['father_mob'],
            'ipadress' => \Request::ip(),
        ]);
    }

}
```

Comment: [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests) has everything you need.

Comment: When you have an URI such as /register?ref=mh2HPLpVSn, you can retrieve ref like this: `request()->ref` in your controller! Let me know if this works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have an URI such as `/register?ref=mh2HPLpVSn` you can retrieve `ref` like this:

```
$request()->ref
```

in your controller! I believe you can also use `$request()->has('ref')` to determine if it's present in the URI.

Hope this helps you!!

Comment: Have you checked this answer?

Comment: didnt work. i am following this tutorial and middle where is not ref value.

https://brudtkuhl.com/building-referral-system-laravel/

Comment: Try: `dd($request()->ref);`

Comment: as i added "Request $request" as function parameter. i got following error


(1/1) ErrorException
Argument 2 passed to Lea\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::create() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, none given, called in E:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\lea\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php on line 33 and defined

Comment: Have you defined it POST method in route?

Comment: its default laravel auth process.  used

Auth::routes();

Comment: https://brudtkuhl.com/building-referral-system-laravel/ can you check where this guy made mistake?? it will be highly helpful for me.

Comment: Try to change route and method to test this works or not! Bcaz i have checked this in my code and seems working fine. Try to test any other route method, i'm sure this works except Auth routes.

Comment: @RjSyedHassanRaza Have you tested this in other route??

Comment: basically i achieved my goal with a different way. but your tip was fine also.

Answer (score 1):

In laravel 6+ inside controller you can use like

```
$request->get('ResourcePath')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your parameters using Request access.
Here one example for get your ref code:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $allParams = $request->all();
    $refParam = $request->ref;
    dd($allParams, $refParam);

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use below format also,

```
    public function handle(Request $request)
    {
        $reference = $request->query('ref');
    
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public function showRegister(Request $request) {
    var_dump(request->ref)
}
```

then you can do things like validation and so on, another possiblity is to change the template of your register form and add a hidden field with the refcode from the ref param and handle the whole request in your register method.

Comment: if i add Request $request then i got following error.

Argument 2 passed to Lea\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::create() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, none given, called in E:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\lea\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php on line 33 and defined